# A lot of similar queries bcs of for loop Django

Tags: python, sql, django

I have for loop in my `get_queryset` function and i'm parsing info from request into my django template but for some reason bcs i try to filter by GUID i got 21 similiar sql queries

I was trying to get CleanSections before my for loop but that didnt help

Any tips how can i solve that?

views.py

```
def get_queryset(self):
    session = requests_cache.CachedSession('budget_cache', backend=backend, stale_if_error=True,
                                           expire_after=360)
    url = config('API') + 'BUDGET'
    response = session.get(url, auth=UNICA_AUTH)

    response_json = None

    queryset = []

    if response_json is None:
        print('JSON IS EMPTY')
        return queryset
    else:
        all_sections = CleanSections.objects.all()

        for item in response_json:
            my_js = json.dumps(item)

            parsed_json = ReportProjectBudgetSerializer.parse_raw(my_js)

            if parsed_json.ObjectGUID == select_front:
                obj = parsed_json.ObjectGUID
            else:
                continue

            for budget in parsed_json.BudgetData:
                budget.SectionGUID = all_sections.filter(GUID=budget.SectionGUID)
                budget.СompletedContract = budget.СompletedContract * 100
                budget.СompletedEstimate = budget.СompletedEstimate * 100
                queryset.append(budget)
    return queryset
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to solve that: we can actually use there dictionary with GUID = key and value name of Section

```
queryset = []
dict_of_sections= {}

all_sections = CleanSections.objects.all()

for i in all_sections:
    dict_of_sections[i.GUID] = i.name


budget.SectionGUID = dict_of_sections[UUID(budget.SectionGUID)]
```